# What is wrong with XML Serialization of a lib class with IL2CPP?

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, deserialization, il2cpp

After setting the scripting backend from Mono to IL2CPP on a Unity Project, it throws an exception at runtime when it runs an XML deserialization of a lib class (from a dll library).

Google Play will soon no longer accept build which doesn't include 64bit version. That's mean in Unity we have to switch from Mono to IL2CPP. The target device is an Android device.

We tried to build the dll library with various versions of the .Net Framework. We also tried to add some instructions in the default constructor (parameterless). Then we used the constructor before the deserialization call, in case of the stripping at build time. We tried to force the stripping level to be disabled by code, but we don't know if it works.

Here is the class where the problem happens, where deserialization fails.

```cs
namespace Api.Common.Licence
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DeviceLicenceFile")]
    public class DeviceLicenceFile
    {
        public DeviceLicenceFile()
        {
            //Email = null; //tried that for an example but is usually empty
        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [...]
    }
}
```

That's my serialization function

```cs
public static T Deserialize<T>(string text)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T obj = (T) (serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)));
    return obj;
}
```

Everything works with Mono but with IL2CPP, it throws the following error =>
"System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Api.Common.Licence.DeviceLicenceFile'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Api.Common.Licence.DeviceLicenceFile cannot be serialized because it does not have a default public constructor"
Of course, we have a parameterless constructor.

EDIT: We're on Unity 2018.4

Comment: Do you make *extensive* use of XML serialization? If not, code like this is fairly easily replaced with "manual" code that just uses `XElement` or `XmlReader`. The framework's XML serialization has a lot of reflection/code generation under the covers, which is a particular challenge for AOT compilation.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I guess we'll do this if don't can't resolve that. It seems to be a bug on Unity, but they said it has been fixed : https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/wsa-xmlserializerexception-thrown-when-running-the-il2cpp-build

Comment: @Shirosamus the upper three comments are from me and people I know ;) It is not fixed for me neither .... however there is a workaround there as well: Switch the `Api Compatibility Level` in the player settings to `.Net Standard 2.0`. This still throws an exception (something about encoding and CP1252) while debugging but you can ignore it as it continues as expected

Comment: I can't just change the API compatibility because some functions need 4.0. But I temporary used XmlReader as a temporary solution.

Comment: Could you use [`DataContractSerializer`](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1264013/trying-to-use-datacontractserializer-with.html)?  If you mark your class with data contract attributes, a parameterless constructor is not required (and not even called).  Note that `DataContractSerializer` doesn't support XML attributes or single-level list serialization so if you XML schema includes those, you can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is probably that IL2CPP is removing the `DeviceLicenceFile` class during build as it's only used via generics / reflection. (IL2CPP does managed code stripping to reduce binary size / build times.)

You can add the whole assembly (or just that type) to a file called `link.xml` that has to be placed in the root of your `Assets` directory, which will tell Unity not to remove that class. See the documentation here for more info: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP-BytecodeStripping.html - you'll see an example there for the file contents you need in the section "How to deal with stripping when using reflection".

Comment: That's not it. We can still call the class and set a property for example (before or after) but it doesn't change anything to the exception. The class is there but the constructor isn't.
I made a start from scratch and the bug is still here. I reported it to unity. It appears that some problems happened before with xml serialization and IL2CPP.
To be continued...

Comment: Did you try adding the whole assembly with Preserve="all"? The code stripper removes even a single unused constructor - it can happen that the one you use from code works but a different one doesn't.

Comment: But sure, IL2CPP bugs are still plenty, so that's totally an option if ^ doesn't solve it.